# Use flutter to imitate chatgpt dialogue

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

**Video example:[text]**(https://github.com/zhao004/netdisc/blob/main/471da6d65ee84581667c6cc9b35c00b4.mp4)

#### **describe:**

**The text typing animation automatically scrolls to the bottom of the list, click the button to terminate typing.**

**How to achieve this effect with flutter?**

**Thank you for helping me write an example.**